# Active Directory Domain Controller setup using external TLD (Godaddy)?

Tags: dns, active-directory, ldap, windows-server

I have been given a task to integrate Active Directory in order to authenticate users and manage group policies. My end-goal is to allow users to enroll their devices (Mac and PC) into Active Directory using their company email address (ie. bob@example.com).

Currently, our company uses Godaddy to manage our DNS for our TLD (example.com). I have used a subdomain to allow public access to our domain controller (dc.example.com - Windows Server 2019). Now, because I've made the Domain Controller a subdomain of example.com, when I create an AD user, I can only register them in the dc.example.com namespace. Rather, I want users to be able to login using the top-level domain example.com.

I have been reading up on domain naming best-practices and everything tells me to use a subdomain rather than duplicating the root domain name. I have actually done the latter... and it works. However, it creates conflicts when I am trying to register Mac computers to Active directory. I don't know why.

I dont want to move away from Godaddy since we have many records stored there, but there MUST be an easier way to do this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is really just for programming questions. You will probably get better help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), which is for server-administration questions. But I do know that a user's email address, and `userPrincipalName` (the email-address-like thing that user's can use to log in) don't have to match the domain name. But I can't comment on Mac.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I will post my question there.